# how to apply bootstrap style to dropdownlistFor and EditorFor in ASP.NET-MVC5 app

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have dropdownListFor in ASP.NET-MVC5 app, mostly I am using Bootstrap style but struggling to do style dropdownList.

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Gender, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Gender, new SelectListItem[]{ 
                                                                new SelectListItem{Value = "Male", Text="Male"},
                                                                new SelectListItem{Value = "Female", Text="Female"}
                                                                }, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "Gender", @class = "form-control" } }

            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Gender, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Also I have EditorFor for integer value, The field shows small button on most right side of textfild that can use to increase and decrease number, also it doesn't have appropriate style, one from bootstrap

```
 @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StudentNumber_UWLID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StudentNumber_UWLID, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "StudentNumber_UWLID", @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StudentNumber_UWLID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: What kind of style are you looking to apply to your drop-down and EditorFor, EditorFor has templates in MVC that can be overridden with editor templates, or you can use TextBoxFor to override the style.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you're passing `new { htmlAttributes = new { ... } }` to `Html.DropDownListFor`. Instead, just pass `new { ... }`. The former is only necessary for `Html.EditorFor` since the parameter you're passing into *there* is `additionalViewData`, whereas for `Html.DropDownListFor`, it's `htmlAttributes`.

Comment: many thanks Chris for dropdowListFor, it works but I am still struggling for Html.EditorFor integer values. I have uploaded image in my question, showing how error is appearing there

Comment: Passing htmlAttributes like that with EditorFor only works when 1) you're using the default editor templates and 2) you're using MVC 5.1+. If you're using a custom template, you'll need to follow my guide here: http://cpratt.co/html-editorfor-and-htmlattributes/. If you're using a lesser version of MVC, you'll either need to upgrade or follow my guide there as well.

Comment: Would never have thought it needed the `htmlAttributes = ` part! Nice answer!